# What is a British English equivalent to 'Fussbudget'?

Tags: synonyms, american-english, british-english, pejorative-language

**Lucy** from Charles Schultz's *Peanuts* strip is often described as a 'fussbudget', for example here: '[Lucy: Fussbudget to Feminist](https://schulzmuseum.org/lucy/)'. What is a British English equivalent to 'fussbudget'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Fussbudget](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fussbudget)***
noun US informal, old-fashioned.

***(UK [fusspot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fusspot))***

> a person who is often not satisfied and complains about things that are not important:
> *"I can't eat this meat - it's too tough." "Stop being such a fussbudget and eat your dinner!"*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Fussbox](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fussbox)***  is another AmE variant:

(Southeastern U.S.)

> a fussy or needlessly fault-finding person
> Also called: fussbudget

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: I have tried to edit this to the correct format and quotation from Cambridge Dictionary but failed. Anyone else care to try?